# Message won't echo

Tags: php, mysql

So I have in my DB.php

```
 public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```

And in my index.php I have this `DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users")`. Why doesn't it echo `Success`?

Comment: Probably because `prepare` is returning `false` or doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Does it work if you put the `echo` before the `if`?

Comment: I suggest you enable exception error mode after creating your PDO instance... `$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`. At least then, when an error occurs, you'll know about it

Comment: Doesn't solve anything. @Barmar

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: do you see the echo or don't you?

Comment: No it doesn't show @Barmar

Comment: @user302975 No, directly after wherever you create your PDO instance, ie `$this->_pdo = new PDO(...)`. You can even set the attribute using the fourth PDO constructor argument if you want, eg `$this->_pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION])`

Comment: I also recommend you don't `catch` any exceptions during development and make sure you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file (requires restarting web server after making changes).

Comment: I don't get any errors. And I have error reporting enabled @Phil

Comment: How are you using this code? Is it in an AJAX server? The caller might not be showing the output.

Comment: @user302975 `error_reporting` is **always** enabled. You may have it set too low. You also need `display_errors` if you hope to see any of them

Answer (score 0):

Try using the double equals... `==`

Your code now is an assignment in the if statement with one equals.

The code in question now is: `if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){`

Try changing this line of code to `if($this->_query == $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){`

I hope this helps. I do not use the object-oriented style of PHP for the most part, but have used the procedural coding style of PHP quiet a bit.

Comment: thats wrong because prepare return a `bool` that is stored in `_query`

Comment: Oops, I did qualify my answer with the fact that I have rarely used the object-oriented version of the PHP API. :/ Even if the `prepare()` function does return a true or false value it is being assigned to the `_query` field of the current object instead of compared to it with the `==` (double equals).